# accessing the market from the options menu

Tags: android, url

I'm trying to find a way to write a URL to get to the Android Market from the Options menu.  I know how to set up the menu, I just don't know how to set up the URL.

Any suggestions?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can open the market site of a certain app via intent. All you need is the package name:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:your.packagename"));
startActivity(intent);
```

*Where `your.packagename` is (obviously) the packagename of the app you are referring to.*